# On library ItemUpdating the Name column's AfterProperty is null

Tags: 2010, document-library, event-receivers

I have an EventReceiver for one of my document libraries which compares some specific columns and their Before and After properties in the `ItemUpdating` event.

When I try to compare the `Name` column its `BeforeProperty` e.g. is "DOC-Test-1" but its `AfterProperty` is null.

Is this because a document library's `Name` column is a calculated field that gets populated much later or what?

Answer (score 0):

I played around with this for a few additional hours to try to see if there was some other property I could check on in the AfterProperties collection and there wasn't.

However the `properties` object in the `ItemUpdating` method does have 2 other properties - `BeforeUrl` and `AfterUrl` which contain the old and the new value of `Name` (aka. `FileLeafRef`)

By comparing the two I was able to find out if the `Name` property had been changed.

```
properties.BeforeUrl != properties.AfterUrl
```